# I'm struggling with the initial set up of a raspberry pi 3 model b and laptop

Tags: raspbian

I could really do with some help on the initial set up of my respberry Pi 3b.

I'm using a Laptop and want the Pi to display on the laptop screen. The aim for the Pi is to have an server on it which will display data(dummy data right now, eventually this will be data taken from a user using a sense hat) I have an SD card which is formatted and have repeatedly tried to install NOOBs or use Pi Bakery to get it up and running. I get a red light and a blinking green light which I originally though meant the pi was installing the OS from the files I had placed on the SD card.

I have - Ethernet Cable, adequate power supply, HDMI and the Pi itself.

When I originally hooked my pi into the laptop I did get an unidentified network but have not seen that since.

Any help would be appreciated so much as I have googled, searched and tried so many things I nearly feel like i'm running around in circles.

Hopefully someone knows where I'm going wrong, thanks a million!

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=437084 Please edit your question and explain where it fails.

Comment: You want to use your laptop's display with your RPI? Does your laptop support this?

Comment: It's entirely unlikely that a laptop will work as a HDMI display. The HDMI on a RPi is a **source**. The HDMI on a laptop is a **source**. The HDMI on a TV or monitor is a **sink**. **Sources** connect to **sinks**, **sinks** display the output.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> I'm using a Laptop and want the Pi to display on the laptop screen.
>   [..]
>   I have - Ethernet Cable, adequate power supply, HDMI and the Pi itself.

As far as I understand this, you are trying to connect the RasPi with an HDMI cable to the laptop and expect that the laptop shows the screen output of the RasPi. This isn't possible because the HDMI port on the laptop isn't an input port. Instead it is an **output** port, like that one on the RasPi, so you can attach a second monitor or a beamer to it and show the laptops screen on it.

It's the same with the Raspberry Pi. You have to attach a monitor or TV with a HDMI **input** port to it to see something. If you don't have such a device you may consider to use the RasPi headless (without monitor) and access it with **ssh** (text console) or **VNC** (graphical user interface).